# In ArcMap graticule ticks on opposite ends of the dataframe do not align

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, grids-graticules

I'm adding tick marks and labels to my dataframe but the ticks on the top do not align with the corresponding ticks on the bottom.  The same is true with left and right ticks.  See image below for visual aid. I want to create a map with three adjacent dataframes but it is difficult to label efficiently if the ticks are not aligned.  My best guess is this is because of the coordinate system and the fact that I'm attempting to display a curved surface in a flat box.  Is this my problem or is there another solution?  I'm using ArcMap 10.3.1 and the coordinate system is coordinate system is NAD 1983 UTM Zone 18N.

[image]

Comment: It looks like your north arrow is skewed.  Check Layers-Properties-General and see if there is a rotation set on the data frame.  Otherwise consider that grid north and true north are different in your area of interest.

Comment: Of course! I rotated the data frame so that the layer was square.  That is certainly the cause of the grid ticks not lining up.  Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you're using a cylindrical projection, in which case this is proper behavior. Please [Edit] the question to specify the coordinate system in use.

Comment: Actually, I removed the rotation and the grid ticks are still not aligned.  The coordinate system is NAD 1983 UTM Zone 18N.

Comment: Right, because there is a difference between the grid north (the map edges shown above) and true north (aligned with the ticks).  You can calculate this difference using the Calculate Grid Convergence tool in ArcGIS which shows a -2.47degree difference for your study area. Set the dataframe to Web Mercator and see what happens to your tick marks.